# "^ backslash not last character on line" in gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

I would like to match a number between `/` and `,` in each line, and increase it by 3. For example

> The Ubiquitous Backslash/49,Black

becomes

> The Ubiquitous Backslash/52,Black

My gawk command is:

```
$ gawk '{b=gensub(/\/([0-9]+),/, "/" (\\1+3) ",") ; print b}' add.jpdf 
gawk: cmd. line:1:                    ^ backslash not last character on line
```

I was wondering what   "^ backslash not last character on line"   means?
Which gawk syntax rule does my solution violate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gensub()` expects a string as second argument. You are trying to concatenate the `/` and `,` around an expression `(\\1+3)` which you assume will be evaluated by the function. It will not. It is evaluated before calling the function. You use `\1` to refer to the matching capture group `()` in the regexp, but you can only use it in a string, not in an expression.

So at best you could use as second argument `"/\\1+3,"`, but you would then get the result `...Backslash/49+3,Black`. You cannot evaluate the 49+3 part in this way.

If you want to do arithmetic on the match, you must first extract the string, do the arithmetic, then place it back in the string.  For example,

```
awk '{ n = split($0, d, /\/([0-9]+),/, s)
       print d[1] "/"(substr(s[1],2)+3)"," d[2] }'
```

This uses gnu awk's `split()` function with a regexp to split the line into 3 parts: the part before the match in `d[1]`, the part after the match in `d[2]`, and the matched string `"/49,"` in s[1]. You should really check `n` is 2 to ensure you got exactly one match.

You can then extract the number from the matched string by simply skipping over the initial `"/"`, do the arithmetic, and concatenate all the parts together again.

---

If the pattern may appear several times in one line of your data, a better solution is to use `match()` to find only the last occurence and cut up the line using `substr()`:

```
awk '{ match($0, /.*\/([0-9]+),/, m)
       a = m[1,"start"]
       b = m[1,"length"]
       if(a)print substr($0,1,a-1) substr($0,a,b)+3 substr($0,a+b)
       else print }'
```

Here the pattern has `.*` added at the front to match only the last occurence.
`a` is set to the character position of the start of the capture group `()` in the regexp, and `b` to its length, so `substr($0,a,b)` is just the number. The final line is reassembled from the two other parts of the original data.

Comment: Thanks. (1) From https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html, `b = gensub(/(.+) (.+)/, "\\2 \\1", "g", a)`, are `\1` and `\2` evaluated by the function or before calling the function? Why does it work? (2) Does `substr(s[1],2)` return the suffice of string `s[1]` starting from the second character of `s[1]`? Will its output include the last character `,`?

Comment: `\1` and `\2` in the string passed to gensub will get replaced by gensub for every match. But the string passed to gensub stays otherwise fixed. In your post you try to provide an expression, but that must be converted into a string (which can contain `\1`) before it gets passed to gensub. The `substr` call is as you described, it starts from character position 2 until the end.

Comment: Thanks. I see. How would you do to "check n is 2 to ensure you got exactly one match"?

Comment: Note that if there are more than one, then it is always the last one that is what I want.

Comment: In `gensub(/\/([0-9]+),/, "/" (\\1+3) ",")`,  what will `\\1+3` in the second argument  become after evaluating and then what will it become after converting to string?

Comment: I added an alternative answer for when there is more than one match on a line. You cannot ask about `\\1+3`, as it is illegal awk, so means nothing.

Comment: Thanks. Can your way deal with the case that there is no match (where we should do nothing)?

Comment: The `if(a)` tests if there was a match. If not just print the line. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @meuh. I was wondering what syntax error  "^ backslash not last character on line" in my original solution mean?