# How can I replace the last match with a string

Tags: text-processing, awk

Given a regular expression and a replacement string, how can I use awk to implement the following:

- if a line contains no match, does nothing;
- if a line contains more than one matches, replace the last match with the replacement string, in the sense of the last match which would be substituted by `gsub()`;
- if a line contains exactly one match, replace the match with the replacement string.

For example, see [" unexpected character '\'" in gawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379066/674)

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need awk? `sed 's/\(.*\)regex/\1replacement/'` should be enough.

Comment: In `awk` you could try something like: `awk '$NF ~ /pattern/{gsub($NF,"replacestring")}1' somefile`. Awk uses `$NF` to indicate the last field in a row.

Comment: show the input sample, do some practice

Comment: @val0x00ff Last field does not imply the last regex location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [" unexpected character '\'" in gawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379066/unexpected-character-in-gawk)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Without that information, it's hard to give advice on the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: @muru your suggestion would fail if the RE started with any variable length atom, such as `x{3,6}` because the greedy `(.*)` could eat up to three of the `x` characters and still be part of an overall valid RE.

Comment: @Tim do you have a valid use-case for this requirement? It's actually very hard to solve reliably as stated - I'm not convinced that in the general case it's even mathematically possible.

Comment: @roaima Yes https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/379066/674  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379066/unexpected-character-in-gawk#comment674096_379076

Comment: @Tim so your use case is not as general as this question makes out? It's a specific `/` + number + `,`. That's much easier to match because (a) it's bounded by invariant atoms, (b) one can follow the match target with a "must not be followed by ( `/` + number + `,` ) RE" construct. It looked a much more interesting question beforehand :-)

Comment: @roaima I am interested in the general case, so I asked here. Why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: @Tim in the general case one could have an RE such as `abc.*abc`. If I have the string `abc xyz abc 123 abc qqq abc 999 abc` what is the "last" RE? It could be the entire string, or it might be the last 11 characters. Or it might be the sequence starting with `abc qqq` in the middle. All are valid answers.  You might get somewhere by reversing the string and RE and binding to the (new) front of the string, but the reversal of an RE isn't going to be straightforward by any means. I'll post this as an answer if you feel there's enough value in it.

Comment: @roaima: the last match  which would be substituted by  `gsub()`.

Answer (score 2):

Not using `gsub()` but use your *Pattern* as the field separator for FS & OFS, then print all the fields except the last two with the OFS intact; next print the second last field followed by the *"REPLACEMENT-STRING"* and then the last field.

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="pat" }
      NF>1{ for(i=1; i<NF-1; i++) printf "%s", $i OFS;
            printf "%s\n", $i "REPLACEMENT-STRING" $NF; next
}1' infile
```

---

Sample input:

```
        pat 1 pat2 patt 3 pat 4
 pat
patt pat
pa t
```

Output:

```
        pat 1 pat2 patt 3 REPLACEMENT-STRING 4
 REPLACEMENT-STRING
patt REPLACEMENT-STRING
pa t
```